# Consulta entre dos fechas

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Deseo obtener la quincena actual, la regla es que este dentro de la fecha_inicio y la fecha_limite como a continuación se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

$actual=Quincena::where('fecha_inicio', '<=',$date)->where('fecha_limite','>=',$date)->first();

Pero al ver lo que trae esa consulta me arroja un null, tomando en cuenta que $date es la fecha de hoy la cual es 2019-06-03 que seria la fecha límite por lo cual debería estar en el rango de fecha_inicio a fecha_limite.
Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Comment: Estás seguro que `$date` es exactamente `2019-06-03` y no tiene alguna hora asignada? Como generaste ese valor? Qué tipo de campo es `fecha_inicio`?

Comment: fecha_inicio y fecha_limite son de tipo date, $date la genero  de la siguiente manera:        $date = Carbon::now(); $date->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: en el modelo `Quincena` tienes algo así `protected $dates = ['fecha_inicio', 'fecha_limite'];`? Prueba con `whereDate(...)` en vez de where en la query.

Comment: No tengo eso en el modelo y ya intente con whereDate y tampoco me funciona, en si el error debe ser el query ya que lo he intentado directo en phpmyadmin y no funciona

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha_inicio <= '2019-06-03' AND fecha_limite >= '2019-06-03';` esa consulta te devuelve algo?

Comment: Si, debe ser el $date como comentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esta línea en el modelo `Quincena`:

```
protected $dates = ['fecha_inicio', 'fecha_limite'];
```

[Hará que laravel convierta automáticamente esas columnas en un objeto Carbon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Y luego haz la query así:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'); 
$quincena = Quincena::whereDate('fecha_inicio', '<=', $date)->whereDate('fecha_limite', '>=', $date)->first();
```